# if (foo or bar or baz) is None:

Tags: python, styles, correctness

I've been refactoring some rather crufty code and came across the following rather odd construct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# ...
if (opts.foo or opts.bar or opts.baz) is None:
    # (actual option names changed to protect the guilty)
    sys.stderr.write("Some error messages that these are required arguments")
```

... and I was wondering if this would ever make any conceivable sense.

I changed it to something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7 
if None in (opts.foo, opts.bar, opts.baz):
    # ...
```

I did fire up an interpreter and actually try the first construct ... it only seems to work if the values are all false **and** the last of these false values is None.  (In other words CPython's implementation seems to return the first true or last false value from a chain of ***or*** expressions).

I still suspect that the proper code should use either the ***any()*** or ***all()*** built-ins which were added 2.5 (the code in question already requires 2.7).  I'm not yet sure which are the preferred/intended semantics as I'm just starting on this project.

So is there any case where this original code would make sense?

Comment: That's terrible. be careful you don't introduce a new bug by fixing this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short-circuiting behavior causes `foo or bar or baz` to return the first of the three values that is boolean-true, or the last value if all are boolean-false.  So it basically means "if all are false and the last one is None".

Your changed version is slightly different.  `if None in (opts.foo, opts.bar, opts.baz)` will, for instance, enter the `if` block if `opts.foo` is None and the other two are 1, whereas the original version will not (because `None or 1 or 1` will evaluate to 1, which is not None).  Your version will enter the `if` when *any* of the three is None, regardless of what the other two are, whereas the original version will enter the `if` only if the *last* is None *and* the other two are any boolean-false values.

Which of the two versions you want depends on how the rest of the code is structured and what values the options might take (in particular, whether they might have boolean-false values other than None, such as `False` or `0` or an empty string).  Intuitively your version does seem more reasonable, but if the code has peculiar tricks like this in it, you never know what corner cases might emerge.

Answer (score 5):

It's behaving that way because `or` is an short-circuit operator, details are in [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). Thus your first `if` statement is equal to:

```
if opts.baz is None
```

We could guess what author of that code expected. I think that, as you mentioned, he thought of using `not all([opts.foo, opts.bar, opts.baz])`.

Comment: To answer his question more specifically: it does seem like the code is in error and I can't think of a case where it would make sense.

Comment: It would make sense if there were no "is" operator there.  But this is technically testing if all values evaluate to false *and* the last is, specifically, a reference to the None singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer

```
 if any(i is None for i in (opts.foo, opts.bar, opts.baz))
```

as it exactly expresses the intended goal.

OTOH,

```
not all([opts.foo, opts.bar, opts.baz])
```

does check for falseness, not for `None`.

The original code doesn't seem to make sense; it seems to have been written by someone unaware what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

let's try both two of your code:

```
In [20]: foo = True

In [22]: bar = None

In [23]: baz = None

In [24]: foo or bar or baz
Out[24]: True

In [25]: (foo or bar or baz) is None
Out[25]: False

In [28]: ((foo or bar or baz) is None) == (None in (foo, bar, baz))
Out[28]: False
```

You can see your rewrite is not same as the original code.

Your first condition only return True when all of your variables is None

```
In [19]: (None or None or None) is None
Out[19]: True
```

so you can rewrite your first condition to:

```
if foo == bar == bar == None:
```

Comment: I acknowledged that the semantics are different; the point here is to speculate on whether there are any plausible cases for the original semantics to be correct.

I think the previous code would have failed in various corner cases which, happily, never seem to have been noted in practice.  (It's part of an internal command line utility which has only been used by a very few staff members).